# Docker run failed to run the container

Tags: docker, microservices

I'm new to docker, trying to build my the first docker container on AWS free tier account t2.micro instance

I am able to build my docker based on below **Dockerfile**.

```
FROM java:8
COPY content-service /
RUN chmod +x /bin/start.sh

CMD bash -C '/bin/start.sh'

EXPOSE 8081

MAINTAINER Velu
```

It's failing and exits while is trying to run the container command following error message is getting.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-30-38 cis-docker]$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
content-service     latest              9fa3ca5a8ac3        10 minutes ago      705.7 MB
docker.io/java      8                   d23bdf5b1b1b        8 months ago        643.1 MB

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-30-38 cis-docker]$ sudo docker --debug run -p 8082:8082 content-service
DEBU[0000] framesize: 18
Starting service.
DEBU[0000] Corrupted prefix: []
DEBU[0000] [hijack] End of stdout
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Change `-C` to `-c` and also what is the content of `/bin/start.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found and fixed this issue.

In my **start.sh** script last line I have this below line.

```
java -cp $CLASS_PATH $JVM_OPTIONS $CLASS_NAME ${ARGUMENTS[@]} & echo $! > $PID_FILE
```

In that line, I did remove this **& echo $! > $PID_FILE**,

**Working:**

```
  java -cp $CLASS_PATH $JVM_OPTIONS $CLASS_NAME ${ARGUMENTS[@]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran your docker file by copying a simple shell script which prints "hello" on to console. It ran successfully.

Also, it does not seem like your docker container is exiting. Docker is running your shell script and exiting gracefully. To verify, check the exit code of your docker run command by running the below command as soon as your docker run is finished.

`echo $?`

If the above command prints "0" on to the screen then docker did not fail.

If you are expecting your shell script to run as a background daemon you need to make sure that your script does not exit. The reason why docker container is exiting as soon as your shell scriptspecified in CMD line your Dockerfile  is finished executing is because Docker's design philosophy is to run [one process per container](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/447/why-it-is-recommended-to-run-only-one-process-in-a-container). In your case that single process is your shell script. So start whatever service you are starting in your shell script as a foreground process and the container will keep running as long as that service is running. As soon as that service dies your container dies which is what you might want.

Hope that helps.